# Is the Infinity MG10 a working generator that consumes no fuel?

Tags: physics, electromagnetism

[Infinity Sav](https://infinitysav.com) are a company pushing a product, the [MG10](https://infinitysav.com/product/mg10/) which is available for pre-order which, they claim, can generate electricity without consuming fuel - i.e. is a free energy machine.

> The Magnetic Generator is complex system with an organized structural arrangement of permanent magnets and bifilar coils and PCB controller with a specially designed software that are used to generate and dispense electrical energy.
>
> Initial start is performed by a battery or any other external source of energy to help motor reach needed RPM. **After that the external source can be disconnected.
> The device is able to operate in autonomous mode and maintain its RPM regardless of amount of useful energy being consumed.**

[This video demonstrates it operating for 5 hours](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zRMHNfug7Ec)

Does this device generate electricity without fuel?

Comment: "maintain its RPM regardless of amount of useful energy being consumed" sounds like ["free energy"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/155/are-there-technologies-that-provide-unlimited-free-energy) or more precisely a [perpetual motion machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#Classification) of the "first kind".

Comment: They aren't manufacturing them yet (they're allowing preorders for "once distributor in that area is assigned"), so there probably isn't much to investigate since they probably aren't giving them out to any independent testers. They do have a [13 year-old patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7095126B2/en) for it (one of [a couple thousand vague patents](https://patents.google.com/?q=H02K53%2f00) for perpetual motion), so that's something.

Comment: It's perpetual motion by another name. Please just Google perpetual motion and be amazed. The company or claimant, if correct, can simply publish their proof and wait for the Nobel Prize in physics for solving the world's energy problems!

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I went back and checked on this company.  As of yesterday, it had been exactly one year since they posted any news on their website.  Their twitter feed has been somewhat active, but it's all been either "look at how cool this looks" or "these people came and looked and were impressed".  Maybe when I check back in next year they might actually have a "working" product.  Or not.

Comment: It's a shame this has received so many downvotes, as it's a good question (by the site's own standards) about a sophisticated and well-presented fraud. This question makes a great opportunity to educate the reader.

Comment: @quant - I suspect that most of the downvotes come from the original form of the question, which _was_ just that bad.  In its current form, you're right that it's decent.  Unrelated, I don't know why I keep coming back to this company every year, but two years on, the website still hasn't been updated and the twitter feed has more of the same types of posts, but no actual _news_.  So they're still active and still haven't done anything concrete to prove that it works.

Comment: Two more years, and the company is gone.  Website is gone, social media hasn't been updated, etc.  Now maybe I can reclaim the tiny fraction of my brain that this has been stuck in.

Answer (score 3):

### No

[Perpetual motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion) machines are impossible - move along. Once a claim of "free" energy is made, the claim is false - the second law of thermodynamics says so.

With a sufficiently large energy store (a battery or a flywheel) a machine can operate for a long time, however, what they are suggesting is that it can operate indefinitely - it can't.

Comment: Give proper reasoning

Comment: Your answer is also incorrect because a perpetual motion machine can exist in a vacuum and move forever

Comment: @Topcode please, learn some physics. A perpetual motion machine is not something that moves forever - most astronomical bodies do that. A perpetual motion machine is something that does work forever without an input of energy.

Comment: per·pet·u·al
/pərˈpeCH(o͞o)əl/
adjective
adjective: perpetual
1.
never ending or changing.
"deep caves in perpetual darkness"

Comment: mo·tion
/ˈmōSH(ə)n/
noun
noun: motion; plural noun: motions
1.
the action or process of moving or being moved.
"the laws of planetary motion"

Comment: @Topcode “perpetual motion machine” compound noun - perpetual is not being used as an adjective. The phrase comes from the most common form a machine that keeps moving in the presence of fiction without input energy.

Comment: I understand your frustration but there's an opportunity here to provide some useful information. I suggest 1) ignore user57512 (except for the first comment, which is valid). 2) Replace "move along" with an explanation, such as 2nd-law violations which explain why perpetual motion would violate some of our most fundamental laws.